# How Angular builds and runs

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-cli

Just want to learn how Angular builds and runs behind the scenes?

Below is what I understood thus far. Want to know if I missed something.

**How Angular builds**

After coding our Angular apps using TypeScript, we use the Angular CLI command to build the app.

`ng build` command compiles the application into an output directory and the build artifacts will be stored in the `dist/` directory.

**Internal Process**

**1.** Angular CLI runs Webpack to build and bundle all JavaScript and CSS code.

**2.**  In turn Webpack calls the TypeScript loaders which fetches all `.ts` file in the Angular project and then transpiles them to JavaScript i.e to a `.js` file, which browsers can understand.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671117/2218697) post says Angular has two compilers:

- View Compiler
- Module Compiler

**Questions on builds**

What is the sequence of calling the build process?

Angular CLI first calls Angular built-in compiler written in TypeScript => then calls the TypeScript Transpiler  =>  then calls the Webpack to bundle and store in the `dist/` directory.

**How Angular runs**

When build is completed, all our app's components, services, modules etc are transpiled to `JavaScript .js` files which is used to run the Angular application in the browser.

Statements in [Angular Docs](https://Angular.io/guide/displaying-data)

1. When you bootstrap with the `AppComponent` class (in main.ts), Angular looks for a `<app-root>` in the `index.html`, finds it, instantiates an instance of AppComponent, and renders it inside the `<app-root>` tag.
2. Angular creates, updates, and destroys components as the user moves through the application.

**Questions on runs**

Although `main.ts` is used in the statement above for explaining the bootstrap process, Isn't Angular app is bootstrapped or started using JavaScript `.js` files?

Isn't all the above statements are done runtime using JavaScript `.js` files?

Does anyone know how all parts fit together in depth?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

*(When I say Angular I mean Angular 2+ and will explicitly say angular-js if I am mentioning angular 1).*

### Prelude: It is confusing

Angular, and probably more accurately angular-cli have merged together a number of trending tools in Javascript that are involved in the build process.  It does lead to a little bit of confusion.

To further the confusion, the term `compile` was often used in angular-js to refer to the process of taking the template's pseudo-html and turning it into DOM elements.  That's part of what the compiler does but one of the smaller parts.

First of all, there is no need to use TypeScript, angular-cli, or Webpack to run Angular.  To answer your question.  We should look at a simple question: "What is Angular?"

### Angular: What does it do?

This section may be controversial, we will see.  **At its core, the service that Angular provides, is a dependency injection mechanism which works across Javascript, HTML, and CSS.**  You write all the little bits and pieces individually and in each little piece you follow Angular's rules for referencing the other pieces.  Angular then weaves that altogether somehow.

To be (slightly) more specific:

- Templates allow HTML to be wired into the Javascript component.  This allows user input on the DOM itself (e.g. clicking a button) to feed into the Javascript component and also allows variables in the Javascript component to control the structure and values in the DOM.
- Javascript classes (including Javascript components) need to be able to access  instances of other Javascript classes they depend on (e.g. classical dependency injection).  A BookListComponent needs an instance of a BookListService which might need an instance of a BookListPolicy or something like that.  Each of these classes has different lifetimes (e.g. services are usually singletons, components are usually not singletons) and Angular has to manage all those lifetimes, the creation of the components, and the wiring of the dependencies.
- CSS rules needed to be loaded in such a way that they only apply to a subset of the DOM (a component's style is local to that component).

One possibly important thing to note is that Angular is not responsible for how Javascript files reference other Javascript files (e.g. the `import` keyword).  That is taken care of by Webpack.

### What does the compiler do?

Now that you know what Angular does we can talk about what the compiler does.  I will avoid getting too technical mainly because I'm ignorant.  However, in a dependency injection system you typically have to express your dependencies with some kind of metadata (e.g. how does a class say `I can be injected`, `My lifetime is blah`, or `You can think of me as a Component type of instance`).  In Java, Spring originally did this with XML files.  Java later adopted annotations and they have become the preferred way to express metadata.  C# uses attributes to express metadata.

Javascript does not have a great mechanism for exposing this metadata builtin.  angular-js made an attempt and it wasn't bad but there were a lot of rules that couldn't be easily checked and were a little confusing.  With Angular there are two supported ways of specifying the metadata.  You can write pure Javascript and specify the metadata manually, somewhat similar to angular-js and just keep following the rules and writing extra boiler-platey code.  Alternatively, you can switch to TypeScript which, as it just so happens, has decorators (those `@` symbols) which are used to express metadata.

So here is where we can finally get to the compiler.  The compiler's job is to take that metadata and create the system of working pieces that is your application.  You focus on all the pieces and all of the metadata and the compiler builds one big interconnected application.

### How does the compiler do it?

There are two ways the compiler can work, runtime and ahead-of-time.  From here on I will assume you are using TypeScript:

- **Runtime:**  When the typescript compiler runs it takes all the decorator information and shoves it into the Javascript code attached to the decorated classes, methods, and fields.  In your `index.html` you reference your `main.js` which calls the `bootstrap` method.  That method is passed your top level module.

The bootstrap method fires up the runtime compiler and gives it a reference to that top level module.  The runtime compiler then starts to crawl that module, all services, components, etc. referenced by that module, and all of associated metadata, and builds up your application.

- **AOT:** Rather than do all the work at runtime Angular has provided a mechanism for doing most the work at build time.  This is almost always done using [a webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) (this must be one of the most popular yet least known npm packages).  It runs after the typescript compilation has run so it sees essentially the same input as the runtime compiler.  The AOT compiler builds up your application just like the runtime compiler but then saves it back out into Javascript.

The advantage here is not just that you can save the CPU time required for the compilation itself, but it also allows you to reduce the size of your application.

### Specific Answers

> Angular CLI First calls angular built in compiler written in
>   Typescript => then calls the Typescript Transpiler => then calls the
>   Webpack to bundle and store in the dist/ directory.

No.  Angular CLI calls Webpack (Angular CLI's real service is configuring webpack.  When you run `ng build` it isn't much more than a proxy to starting Webpack).  Webpack first calls the Typescript compiler, then the angular compiler (assuming AOT), all while bundling your code at the same time.

> Although main.ts is used in Statement above for explaining bootstrap
>   process, Isn't angular app is bootstrapped or started using Javascript
>   .js files ?

I'm not entirely certain what you are asking here.  `main.ts` will be tranpiled down into Javascript.  That Javascript will contain a call to `bootstrap` which is the entry point to Angular.  When `bootstrap` is done  you will have your full Angular application running.

> This post says Angular has two compilers:
>
> View Compiler
>
> Module Compiler

To be honest I'm just going to claim ignorance here.  I think at our level we can just think of it all as one big compiler.

> Does anyone know how all parts fit together in depth ?

I hope the above satisfied this.

### Don't @ Me: Angular does more than dependency injection

Sure.  It does routing, view building, change detection and all kinds of other things.  The compiler does actually generate Javascript for view building and change detection.  I lied when I said it was just dependency injection.  However, the dependency injection is at the core and enough to drive the rest of the answer.

### Should we call it a compiler?

It probably does a lot of parsing and lexing and definitely generates a lot of code as a result so you could call it a compiler for that reason.

On the other hand, it isn't really translating your code into merely a different representation.  Instead it is taking a bunch of different pieces of code and weaving them into consumable pieces of a larger system.  The bootstrap process then (after compiling, if necessary) takes those pieces and plugs them into the Angular core.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Before accepting your answer I have doubt in  Your Statement `The compiler does actually generate `Javascript` for view building and change detection.` It is not a lie. That's what the compiler does isn't ? And angular does the dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  the lie I was referring to was “At its core, the service that Angular provides, is a dependency injection mechanism” because while Angular does that it is not all it does and not even all the compiler does.

Comment: If Angular is abstraced as a new "language" with features like components, directives, services, and so on. It can be called a compiler. Complie Angular language into raw js and html.

Answer (score 10):

Let me start from the beginning.

In my application I directly run application from `Webpack`.

To build and run the application we use **webpack --progress** and **webpack-dev-server --inline** command the has been written in `package.json` as below

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --inline ",
    "build": "webpack --progress"

  }
```

When we run `webpack --progress` command it start's reading `webpack.config.js` file where it find the entry point as below.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
            },
            /* Embed files. */
            {
                test: /\.(html|css)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: /\.async\.(html|css)$/
            },
            /* Async loading. */
            {
                test: /\.async\.(html|css)$/,
                loaders: ['file?name=[name].[hash].[ext]', 'extract']
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

and then it read's all `Typescript` file and compile's based on rules declared in the `tsconfig.json` file and than convert's it to respective `.js` files and it's map file.

If it runs without any compilation error it will create `bundle.js` file with names as we declared in the `Webpack` output section.

Now let me explain why we use loaders.

**awesome-typescript-loader, angular2-template-loader**  We use these loader to compile the `Typescript` file on the base declared in the `tsconfig.json` file and angular2-template-loader searches for `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` declaration's inside of the Angular 2 Component metadata and replaces the paths with the corresponding require statement.

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    }
```

We use above resolve section to tell `Webpack` to convert `Typescript` to `JavaScript` file

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
```

Plugins section is used to inject third party framework or file.
In my code I am using this to inject `index.html` of destination folder.

```
 devtool: 'source-map',
```

Above line is used to see the `Typescript` file in browser and debug it mostly used for developer code.

```
 loader: 'raw-loader'
```

The above `raw-loader` is used to load the `.html` and `.css` file and bundle them along with `Typescript` files.

At the end when we run **webpack-dev-server --inline** it will create own server and boot-up the application as the path mentioned in `web-pack.config.js` file where we mentioned destination folder and entry point.

In `Angular` 2 entry point of most application is `main.ts` where we mention the initial bootstrap module for example(app.module) this module contain complete  application information such as all directive,service,modules,components and routing implementation of whole application.

**Note:** 
Many people's having doubt that why `index.html` only boot-up the application, even though they have not mentioned any where.
The answer is when `Webpack` serve command runs it create own serve and by default it load `index.html` if you have not mention any default page.

I hope that given information help some people's.

Comment: Appreciate you have tried to explain, It would be better if you could explain in more clear sequential manner. So  You don't use `Angular CLI` for building `Angular` apps and use `Webpack` directly how ?

Answer (score 6):

**How Angular builds ?**

The `Angular CLI` calls `Webpack`, when `Webpack` hits a `.ts` file it passes it off to `TypeScript` Compiler which has a output transformer which compiles `Angular` templates

So build sequence is:

`Angular CLI` => `Webpack` => `TypeScript` Compiler => `TypeScript` Compiler calls the `Angular` compiler in compile time.

**How Angular runs ?**

`Angular` bootstraps and runs using `Javascript` file.

Actually bootstrap process is runtime and happens before opening the browser. This takes us to our next question.

So If the bootstrap process happens with `Javascript` file then why `Angular` Docs uses `main.ts` TypeScript file to explain bootstrap process ?

`Angular` Docs just talk about the `.ts` files since that's the source.

This is brief answer. Appreciate if anyone can answer in depth.

Credits goes to @[Toxicable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4083539/toxicable) for answering my questions in chat.

Answer (score 4):

Might be late for this answer, but there have been a really good talk recently about this topic, which starts from a beginner viewpoint and goes in depth. Instead of trying to summarize or point out misinformation in this thread with my words, I'll just link the video by [Kara Erickson: How Angular works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0o-4yc2n-8).

She is the  tech lead on the Angular framework, and does a really good presentation on:

- what are the main parts of the Angular framework
- how does the compiler work, what does it produce
- what is a "Component definition"
- What is an application bootstrap, how does it work

Comment: Thank you for contribution :) , Appreciate.

Comment: It mainly focusses om runtime processes and only briefly touches compilation strategies/processes. Just the “opposite” of the OP’s need.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 9+ uses AOT (Ahead of Time Compilation) which means it takes all the bits scattered in various files i.e. component (.ts + .html + .css), modules (.ts) and construct browser understandable JavaScript which at runtime is downloaded and executed by the browser.

Prior to Angular 9 it was JIT (Just in time Compilation) where the code was compiled as it was required by the browser.

For details see: [Angular AOT Documentaiton](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

> So If the bootstrap process happens with Javascript file then why
>   Angular Docs uses main.ts TypeScript file to explain bootstrap process
>   ?

This is part of the transformed .js version of main.ts emitted by `ng build` which is not yet uglified and minified, How do you expect for a beginner to comprehend this code? doesn't it look way much complicated?

```
Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__angular_platform_browser_dynamic__["a" /* platformBrowserDynamic */])().bootstrapModule(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__app_app_module__["a" /* AppModule */])
    .catch(function (err) { return console.log(err); });
```

and with `ng build --prod --build-optimizer` which uglifies and minifies your code in order to optimize it, generated bundles are compact and are in bit-unreadable format.

`webpackJsonp([1],{0:function(t,e,n){t.exports=n("cDNt")},"1j/l":function(t,e,n){"use strict";n.d(e,"a",function(){return r});var r=Array.isArray||function(t){return t&&"number"==typeof t.length}},"2kLc`

whereas main.ts file is human readable and lucid, that's why the angular.io uses main.ts to explain the bootstrap process of angular application.[Angular: Why TypeScript?](https://vsavkin.com/writing-angular-2-in-typescript-1fa77c78d8e8) apart from this if you had been an author of such a great framework what approach you would have used in order to make your framework popular and user-friendly? wouldn't you go for clear and concise explanation rather than a complicated one? I agree angular.io documentation lacks in-depth explanation and it is not pretty great but as far I have seen they are striving hard to make it better.