# Angular6 import bootstrap file in several scss component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

i have a question regarding the importation of the same scss file in different composents, for instance bootstrap scss file from the node module,
Will it compile it as a single file or Will it duplicate it depanding on the number of composent that i imported in ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Angular will not duplicate any files but simply reference the same file. I can't really find any references to back up this claim exactly, but I have never heard of file duplication with any compiler, more so, that would be very inefficient. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942691/how-angular-builds-and-runs) SOF question which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing bootstrap in several components. It means you have kept bootstrap file either in assets and just passing in `index.html` as

```
<link href="...." rel="stylesheet">
```

or,

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

### angular.json

```
styles:[
"node_modules/scss/bootstrap.scss"
]
```

So, by `importing` each time in `several components` , it is compiling it as a single file. However, it is referencing bootstrap file each time.