# ng build --watch: what happens behind the scenes?

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, angular-ivy

I have an Angular application where a lot of rebuilds are necessary, to avoid long build times I use a deamon like process where I execute the `ng build --prod --watch`  command. This works fine BUT I cannot find a lot of documentation about the `ng build` or `ng build --watch` command and before I use this in production I want to understand what happens behind the scenes.

Could you provide me with information or some usefull links about the angular cli especially the build command and the --watch flag.

Is it there a mechanism or an API like tool where I can use the ng build --watch like behaviour to build my "own" tool with some additional features client side notification, replace or add new/changed files etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Angular builds and runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942691/how-angular-builds-and-runs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, of course I read this post before creating my own. It explains in depth the general concept but no further information on the --watch flag.

Comment: Is it possible to use the --watch flag for production or is it only a dev tool like ng serve, how does the angular cli handle the "partial" rebuild and is there any chance to hook into the build --watch process?

Comment: I see no reason to build in production, ever.