# Confused about the difference between Webpack vs Ivy VS AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I know that webpack in angular responsible for the Compiling code as a Build Automation tool it gets all scripts and combines them into a bundle of fills to optimize the App.

I understand the difference also between JIT VS AOT so my question is? which contains which, is the webpack contains JIT, AOT, and IVy.

Also based on angular documentation JIT is the default but I read also from 9 to the latest version, they used IVY as view engine with AOT so which is the default.

Comment: Webpack itself is very common tool and it knows nothing about Angular, AOT, JIT, etc.

All work is done by plugins and loaders, e.g.: AngularCompilerPlugin, angular2-template-loader, awesome-typescript-loader, ...

Comment: But they said that  Webpack in angular responsible for the Compiling code , JIT and AOT  also for the Compiling code

Answer (score 0):

Ivy is a compiler of Angular-specific files to JavaScript. It has replaced ViewEngine compiler starting from Angular 9. They are both capable of JIT and AOT compilation modes. To my understanding, webpack is using them in its build pipeline to produce the resulting module.

Comment: Can I know who works first  ? the Webpack or JIT / AOT?  Can you explain the steps?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942691/how-angular-builds-and-runs