# Angular: ngc or tsc?

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation, tsc

I have been using tsc, but see that angular.io emphasizes ngc. I am wondering if there are advantages to either or if I should choose one over the other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of build? AOT or JIT?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

tsc and ngc have different purposes and it's not about selecting one over the other.

tsc is a TypeScript compiler, and you need it to generate JavaScript if your app is written in TypeScript.

ngc is an Angular-specific compiler. It doesn't turn the TypeScript code into JavaScript.  It does a "finishing touch" to make your app bundles ready for rendering by the browser. In particular, it turns your components templates into inline JavaScript. If you do a prod build with Ahead of Time (AoT) compilation, the ngc does its part before the bundles are built. In dev mode we use Just-in-Time compilation: the templates are not precompiled, the ngc compiler is included into the bundles, and it compiles the templates after the browser loaded your bundles.

Comment: This answer explains very clearly, in just a 'few' lines of text, what a 1000 pages of official documentation for some reason cannot. I could never for the life of me find out the exact roles of TSC and NGC within the Angular2+ story, how they relate to one another and whether or not one rules out the other.

So thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: @Kornelis I'm glad it was useful for you :)

Comment: So If i release my Angular app on Tomcat or on IIS server, it will use AOT compiler or Just in time compiler ......

Comment: As long as you do production build (--prod), it'll do AOT.